# Fatal error: When using WHERE clause in query issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 queries on a page, that use the same statement structure i have used where statements in all of them. My issue is 2/3 of the queries work. The second query keeps reading me back the error message below, only once i have added a WHERE clause to the query, and the Fatal error disappears once the WHERE clause as been delete.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function data_seek() on boolean in ... on line 235

**Line 235 holds this code.**

```
 $fc_sel->data_seek(0);
```

**My full code**

```
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX); //overrid a common php nonsense error
 $REST_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['Resturant_ID']);
 $fc_sel = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Food_Cat WHERE = '$REST_id'");
 $fc_sel->data_seek(0);

 $i = 1;

 while ($output = $fc_sel->fetch_assoc()) {
$fc_run .= $output['Food_Cat_name'] . $output['Food_Cat_Desc'] . '<br>';
$_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] = $output['Food_Cat_name']; //echo out product name
$_SESSION['Food_Cat_Desc'] = $output['Food_Cat_Desc']; //echo out product desc
$_SESSION['Food_Cat_ID'] = $output['Food_Cat_ID']; //echo out product desc
```

I have looked all over the internet and i cannot seem to find an answer. Any guidance or a break down of my mistake would be appreciated.

Comment: If you had any kind of error handling at all then you would know what's wrong. It needs to know WHAT is equal to the value, you have no left-side on your `=`!

Comment: Your mysqli_report call is quite peculiar. I can't imagine a case where it can be useful.

Comment: You have an SQL error, WHERE = '$REST_id' . I guess it should be WHERE `Resturant_ID` = '$REST_id' or something like that

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i do have error handler right at the top of my page and this is the error i am receiving

Comment: @MarkvanHerpen you are totally right. i do not know how i missed that